# AVOID CASE SENSITIVE IN SSRS EXPRESSION

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I AM USING THIS EXPRESSION IN SSRS 
1.

```
=iif(Parameters!SchemeConsolidateYn.Value="y",false,true)
```

2.

```
=IIF(Parameters!ConsolidatedYn.Value="y","Consolidated",First(Fields!BranchName.Value, "DataSet2"))
```

BUT WHEN I AM GIVING "Y"(CAPITAL Y ) EXPRESSION TAKING OTHER VALUE..
MY QUESTION IS HOW TO AVOID CASE SENSITIVE HERE ,,.. SO I CAN USE BOTH( Y OR y)
  note: in both expression i am facing the same issue ( case sensitive)

Comment: Please stop SHOUTING!

Comment: can you not use something like LCase(string) 
which will return you string in lower case and then simply use "y" to compare

Comment: Just use `OR`. `=IIF(Parameters!ConsolidatedYn.Value="y" OR Parameters!ConsolidatedYn.Value="Y","Consolidated",First(Fields!BranchName.Value, "DataSet2"))` But I think @AnkUser would work best.

Comment: I would convert your parameter to UPPER and compare it to a capital Y like `=IIF(UPPER(Parameters!ConsolidatedYn.Value)="Y" ... `

Comment: @HannoverFist means `UCase` which is SSRS VBA's function for uppercase, rather than `UPPER` which is Sql Server's uppercase function. Now, if your dataset is coming from a SQL source, you could `UPPER` it in your Sql statement but using `UCase` in your SSRS VBA expression is probably clearer.

Comment: @wei_DBA Your comment is really helpful.Thank You